# Javascript: Object not accessible after closing parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

So I have a parent window who is opening itself to a new window (just to remove the status bar, toolbar, others). After closing the parent window, the passed variable return blank string. Sometimes it returns this error message: "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable." I really need to access this variable even after closing the parent window. Any suggestions?

```
var _env = {};
$(window).load(function()
{
    /**
     *
     * If initialization was not yet performed, start the initialization.
     * Otherwise, show application.
     *
     **/

    if (window.opener)
    {
        /* Start transition to the new window */
        window.blur();
        _env = window.opener._env;

        console.log(_env["title"]);

        /* Show system */
        window.opener.close();
        window.focus();

        console.log(_env["title"]); // Returns blank
    }
    else
    {
        /* Some process manipulating the '_env' variable */
        /* .... */
        /* .... */

        window.open("./index.html", _env["title"], "directories=0, menubar=0, toolbar=0, titlebar=0, resizable=1, width=" + _env["winWidth"] + ", height=" + _env["winHeight"]);
        window.focus();
        window.open("","_self", ""); // To prevent prompt on closing..
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the object to JSON, and set `window.location.href` to it.  You can then extract it when you need the data, and there won't be any issues with references because you're creating a new object.